# Printing logout button via the view on the condition that the user is logged in (using codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, parse-error

I've been tinkering with the echo statement to make my logout button print in my header (when a user is logged in) but I keep either getting errors of this nature:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';' in /vagrant/web/Project/application/views/_header.php on line 19 Call Stack: 0.0013 634608 1. {main}() /vagrant/web/Project/index.php:0 0.0123 636728 2. require_once('/vagrant/web/Project/system/core/CodeIgniter.php') /vagrant/web/Project/index.php:202 0.1486 1025392 3. call_user_func_array() /vagrant/web/Project/system/core/CodeIgniter.php:359 0.1486 1025528 4. Fp_controller->index() /vagrant/web/Project/system/core/CodeIgniter.php:0 0.1486 1025976 5. Viewlib->loadview() /vagrant/web/Project/application/controllers/fp_controller.php:12 0.1487 1026192 6. CI_Loader->view() /vagrant/web/Project/application/libraries/Viewlib.php:16 0.1487 1027600 7. CI_Loader->_ci_load() /vagrant/web/Project/system/core/Loader.php:419

or the url will just be completely screwed up (it will literally have "base_url();" instead of the actual base url name that I declared in my config file. Could somebody help me?

Header view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Final Project Incorporated</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Navigation:</h1>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>fp_controller/index">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>fp_controller/directory">Employee Directory</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>fp_controller/form">Add Employee Form</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>fp_controller/login">Login</a></li>

                <?php 

            if ($this->session->userdata('isLoggedIn')) {
Line 19>>>>              echo "<li>" . "<a href=" . "'" echo base_url();"'" .     "fp_controller/logout" . ">" . "Logout" . "</a>" . "</li>";
            }

            ?>

        </ul>

        <hr />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put an echo inside a php statement, just concatenate:

```
echo "<li>" . "<a href=" . "'".base_url()."'" ."fp_controller/logout" . ">" . "Logout" . "</a>" . "</li>";
```

You could also use site_url() for this, which takes care of url building:

```
echo '<li><a href="'.site_url('fp_controller/logout').'">Logout</a></li>";
```

Another way of writing it, with short form:

```
<?php if ($this->session->userdata('isLoggedIn')) : ?>
   <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('fp_controller/logout');?>">Logout</a></li>
<?php endif;
```

This way you reduce any possibile error with escaping quotes etc, just write plain html and use php as templating engine. Personally, I find this way easier to read and less error prone.

Answer (score 1):

A simple Log out example which i am using in my application. I am assuming you will save user data in session with array name `$logged_in_user`.

```
View:

<p class="user">Hello, <?php echo $logged_in_user['user_name'] ?> | <a href="<?php echo ROOT_FOLDER ?>/controller_name/logout_function_name">Logout</a></p>


Controller:

public function logout_function_name(){
        $this->model_file_name->logout_function_name();
        redirect("/controller_function_name/page_name_where_you_want_to_redirect");
    }

Model:

public function logout()
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
}
```